# React Swiper JS custom slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

The main active slide is the large image on the right. When you click the Forward button, it should scroll to the right and substitute the next image for the main one. The pictures show roughly how it should work. The slides should not be repeated.

> [image]
> When we press the forward button
> [image]

I tried to solve this with two sliders - Main and Thumbs slider, but it looks crooked and I think there is a much more concise solution than mine.

```
onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
    const swiperElement = thumbsSwiper.el;
    const swiperWrapper = swiperElement.querySelector('.swiper-wrapper');

    const activeSlide = swiperElement.querySelector('.swiper-slide-thumb-active');
    const slides = swiperElement.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');
    const howManySlides = thumbsSwiper.slides.length;
    slides.forEach((element) => {
        element.classList.remove('none');
        if (element.classList.contains('swiper-slide-thumb-active')) {
            element.classList.add('none');
        }
    });
    swiperWrapper.insertBefore(activeSlide, slides[howManySlides]);
}}
```